# How to store unknown number of numbers

Tags: assembly, 68000

What I'm trying to do is read from a file which only has positive integers, then sort the integers and output them.

The problem is that I don't know how many lines (each line has a number) the file I'm trying to read from will have.

Is there a way to store the numbers in the address/data registers even though I don't know how many numbers there will be?

EDIT: Going to explain a little more. The data file will probably have less than 14 inputs, The question is, how will I be able to put the <14 numbers into different registers without hard coding each individual register?

Comment: Sounds like you'll either need some dynamic data structure or - if you must use a statically allocated structure - put a cap on the maximum number of lines you can read.

Comment: Why do you need to put all the data in registers? There's a limited number of registers. Why not just read the data into a static or dynamic buffer? You may want to look into indirect addressing if you are not familiar with that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading from a file, the OS will offer you an "End of File check".  If you read line-by-line, it is easy to count lines; the total number of lines what the line counter says when the EndOfFile check goes true.

To *store* this set of numbers, you probably want a contiguous block of storage which is big enough.  You can decide a maximum size in advance and simply declare a large enough buffer statically.

An alternative is to dynamically allocate memory (see calls to Malloc or something similar the OS offers) to hold some amount larger than what you expect, and fill values into that space until it is full.  If there is more to the file, allocate a larger chunk, copy the values collected so far from the old chunk, release the old chunk, and continue.  A simple rule is to allocate initially what you think is 2 sigma times the average number of values you expect (e.g., if you think files contain typically 100 values, you might allocate a buffer of 150 slots initially) to handle most case with just the initial allocation.  If you need to reallocate, then double the size of the last buffer you allocated (e.g, switch to 300, 600, ...).  This keeps the reallocation overhead very low.

A third choice is to collect your values in a set of fixed size buffers, e.g., allocate 100 slots for each new block) and fill them in as you read.  You now have a set of buffers (you can link them in a linear list, or build an array to track them using the technique in the previous paragraph).  This has the downside of complicating your sort, so I don't think this is the best method.